# Conditional ETL in Camel based on matching .md5

Tags: apache-camel

Looked through the docs for a way to use Camel for ETL just as in the site's examples, except with these additional conditionals based on an md5 match.

Like the camel example, myetl/myinputdir would be monitored for any new file, and if found, file of ${filename} would be processed.

Except it would first wait for ${filename}.md5 to show up, which would contain the correct md5. If ${filename}.md5 never showed up, it would simply ignore the file until it did.

And if ${filename}.md5 did show up but the md5 didn't match, it would be processed but with an error condition.

Found suggestions to use crypto for matching, but have not figured out how to ignore the file until the matching .md5 file shows up. Really, these two files need to be processed as a matched pair for everything to work properly, and they may not arrive in the input directory at the exact same millisecond. Or alternately, the md5 file might show up a few milliseconds before the data file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) to combine the two files based on their file name. If your files are suitably named, then you can use the file name (without extension) as the correlation ID. Continue the route once `completionSize` equals 2. If you set groupExchanges to true then in your next route step you have access to both the file to compute the hash value for and the contents of the md5 file to compare the hash value against. Or if the md5 or content file never arrived within `completionTimeout` you can trigger whatever action is appropriate for your scenario.